# Cannot generate crosstab with tPivotToColumnsDelimited

Tags: talend

I have this excel source :

[image]

I want to make an exercise with Talend for generating a crosstab from it but there is error in the console. I did the crosstab from excel and I got this :

[image]

So how to proceed in Talend to get the similar result ?

**EDIT :**

here is the error :

`Exception in component tFileInputExcel_1
jxl.read.biff.BiffException: Unable to recognize OLE stream
    at jxl.read.biff.CompoundFile.<init>(CompoundFile.java:116)
    at jxl.read.biff.File.<init>(File.java:127)
    at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:268)
    at projet_test.tableau_croise_dynamik_0_1.tableau_croise_dynamik.tFileInputExcel_1Process(tableau_croise_dynamik.java:679)
    at projet_test.tableau_croise_dynamik_0_1.tableau_croise_dynamik.runJobInTOS(tableau_croise_dynamik.java:1418)
    at projet_test.tableau_croise_dynamik_0_1.tableau_croise_dynamik.main(tableau_croise_dynamik.java:1275)`

**UPDATE 2 :**

the sum are not displayed :

[image]

So how to show the sum ?

Comment: What have you done so far? Provide sample design of your job. Also provide the sample data in text rather than image.

Comment: I edited my post for the excel error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the error is in your tFileInputExcel you need to put the right extention.
If your file is .xls or .xlsx you need to put the right extention in the parameter of you fileinputexcel.

[image]

You need a tPivotToColumnDelimited like

[image]

Comment: I followed your suggestion but still get errror , see my update post to see the error.

Comment: ok , I checked the checkbox and it works , but the sum are not displayed , see my update in the post showing the photo of the result.

Comment: yes maybe you need a taggregaterow for the total after the tpivottocolumn